# Magento2 How to Integrate background image in my email template

Tags: magento2, email, magento2.3, image, email-templates

I want to integrate a image in tag as background in style for my account creation email template.

Where can I place this image in my folder and how can I call the image as background.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to create plugin then you can add your images from module or theme level web/images folder and give the path to your images in email.

```
<img src="{{view url='Package_Modulename/images/customimg.png'}}" height="30" width="30" alt="{{trans 'Custom image'}}" />
```

**I hope this will help**

Answer (score 3):

first you have to set **image url** in variables like below way..

**step1:**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $assetRepo;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo
    ) 
    {
        $this->assetRepo = $assetRepo;
        parent::__construct($context);   
    }

    public function Emaildata()
    {
        //return current customer ID
        $variables['image_url'] = $this->assetRepo->getUrl(
            'Vendor_Module::images/image.png',
            ['_area' => 'frontend']
        );
    }

    $this->mail(....,$variables)
}
```

**step2:** 
calling html template `image_url`

```
<img src="{{var image_url}}" width="100px" height="100px">
```

Answer (score 3):

**Go to admin Email template:**

```
Marketing -> Communications -> Email Templates & open email template Ex. New Order
```

```
<div class="order-info" style="background: url({{view url='images/order-info.png'}}) center center no-repeat;">
```

**Image folder path will be:** `app/design/frontend/Vendor_Name/Theme_Name/web/images`

I hope it will be work for you also.